# Django: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison - Postman works

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I have a Django backend running as a service on an Ubuntu machine. After a while, I am getting this error when trying to execute my requests:

maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

I have attached to the process and found where the problem is occurring:

```
    response = requests.delete( apiUrlAddEntries, verify=False )
    return response
```

The debugger does not get inside the Delete call, it just trigger that exception. However, if I send the same delete call using Postman (on the same machine, toward the same server), all goes through fine.

What do you think? Is it because the request lib? What cold make it run from Postman side and not from the request lib call? If I restart the service, it goes fine, for a while that is.

Comment: Impossible to tell from that code snippet. Also, is that the **exact** error message? If so, what/where is *comparison*

Comment: It's hard to say without more information, but I have a couple possible ideas:
1. Check the logs? Are there any errors or warnings related to the requests that are failing?
2. Check your server resources? Are these large requests such that you may be running out of CPU or memory? 
3. Double-check that you don't have an infinite recursion somewhere in your code?